# Blockhash: Register the block number

Tags: blockchain, blocks, hash, randomness

I am reading the following article from a website:
[bad randomness](https://medium.com/dedaub/bad-randomness-is-even-dicier-than-you-think-7fa2c6e0c2cd)

In the context of Blockhash the author says:
For instance, a good protocol (formulating a random trial as a “bet”)
is the following:

> • accept a bet, with payment, register the block number of the bet
>   transaction
>
> • in a later transaction, compute the blockhash of the
>   earlier-registered block number, and use it to determine the success
>   of the bet.

Somebody please guide me what is meant by registered block number.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasing is a bit strange. You basically have to store a future blockhash number to be used, e.g., just the current blocknumber + 2. This blockhash is completely unknown at the time of the transaction, can only be influenced to some degree by Ethereum miners and thus provides a good-enough source of randomness for some protocols.

The approach would basically be:

1. Store future block number in the last accepted bet.
2. Inside the determine winner function evaluate the blockhash from the block number and compute the winner. Also handle the case if no one called this function for more than 256 blocks after the stored block number (see your other question: [Blockhash Minus-256 Problem](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83921/blockhash-minus-256-problem)).

This is a simple example with a single function to gamble with ETH:

```
mapping (address => uint256) gameWeiValues;
mapping (address => uint256) blockHashesToBeUsed;

function playGame() public {
    if (!blockHashesToBeUsed[msg.sender]) {
        // first run, determine block hash to be used                          
        blockHashesToBeUsed[msg.sender] = block.number + 2; // use 2 or more
        gameWeiValues[msg.sender] = msg.value;
        return;
    }

    uint256 randomNumber = uint256(blockhash(blockHashesToBeUsed[msg.sender]));

    blockHashesToBeUsed[msg.sender] = 0;
    gameWeiValues[msg.sender] = 0;

    // randomNumber = 0 means expired blockhash, player looses
    if (randomNumber != 0 || randomNumber % 2 == 0) {
        uint256 winningAmount = gameWeiValues[msg.sender] * 2;
        msg.sender.transfer(winningAmount);    
    }
}
```

See also https://soliditydeveloper.com/2019-06-23-randomness-blockchain.

Comment: It means there is no concept of registering the block number. How can we store the future block number in the last accepted bet?

Comment: @zak100 See my example, the line `blockHashesToBeUsed[msg.sender] = block.number + 2;` does exactly that.

Comment: Why not just "Store the block number in the last accepted bet" instead of "Store future block number in the last accepted bet.", What you mean by future here?

Comment: @zak100 `block.number + 2` is a block number in the future, i.e., a block that is not yet mined and thus has an unknown block hash. (I think there was some issue with using `block.number + 1` but cannot remember what exactly right now)

Comment: I think there is a problem in your code because you are not checking if 'block.number +2' is greater than 256 or not?

Comment: @zak100 Let's assume somebody calls `playGame()` the first time at block 100. It would then store block 102 inside `blockHashesToBeUsed[msg.sender]`. Now let's assume he calls `playGame()` the second time at block 400 (> 102 + 256). This would result in `blockhash(blockHashesToBeUsed[msg.sender]) = blockhash(102) = 0x0` => `randomNumber = 0`. Later on we check if `if (randomNumber != 0)` and a player automatically losses if it's 0.

Comment: What is the purpose of randomNumber%2?

Comment: @zak100 Just an example which will be 50% of the times 0 and 50% of the times 1 ensuring a fair game between player and bank. It's the modulo operator which gives the remainder after division. In other words `number % 2 == 0` means 'is the number even (=> true) or odd (=> false)?'.