# Blockhash Minus-256 Problem

Tags: blocks, hash, randomness, random

What is meant by Blockhash Minus-256 Problem?

I am reading an article at:

[Bad Randomness](https://medium.com/dedaub/bad-randomness-is-even-dicier-than-you-think-7fa2c6e0c2cd)

It talks about Blockhash Minus-256 problem but does not explain much about it. As a result I can’t understand this problem.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is talking about only the last 256 blocks being available to the contract, see https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.8/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties under `blockhash`.

There is a whole section about it in your article:

> As mentioned earlier, the blockhash function is only defined for the
>   previous 256 blocks. (In the non-immediate future, EIP-210 aims to
>   change this.) Therefore, if the second step of the above protocol is
>   performed too late (>256 blocks later) or too early (in the same
>   transaction as the first step), the result (zero) of blockhash will be
>   known to an attacker.

This was for example the case in the SmartBillions hack: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/74d3dc/smartbillions_lottery_contract_just_got_hacked/

Comment: last 256 blocks are good because the result of blockhash will not be zero and henceforth not known to the attacker, why its regarded as a problem?

Comment: @zak100 Anything within 256 blocks is no problem. Maybe you are referring the the second part of the article with CryptoKitties trying to circumvent the issue by choosing a new block once the old one is not reachable? Which is like the author states exploitable with try-and-error method. The better solution is to let the player loose on expired blockhashes.